# Change picture when click on it (html, css & js)

Tags: javascript, html, css

First, I apologize for my poor English, I'm French ^^.

I'm a beginner in html, css & js.

For my job, I've create an html page.  On this page, there is a picture. When I click on this picture, I want it to change (see below):

- No click, picture 1.
- One click, picture 2.
- Two click, picture 1.
- ...

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col c1-8">
  <a id="btn4" onclick="toggle(this)" data-on="/trigger/7" data-off="/trigger/8" href="/trigger/8">
    <img src="images/all_logos_2/b_ON-OFF_v1_off.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function toggle(element) {
  var onLink = element.getAttribute('data-on');
  var offLink = element.getAttribute('data-off');
  if (element.getAttribute("href") == offLink){
    element.setAttribute("href", onLink);
  } else if (element.getAttribute("href") == onLink){
    element.setAttribute("href", offLink);
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to proceed.

Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: Show us some of you code.

Comment: I'll know what have you done? Give us some code to work whit it.

Comment: Did you try something at least ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For us to be able to answer this question you will need to provide some code showing what you have tried so far. In its current state the question is a bit too broad to be answered and as a result may be closed.

Comment: Of course I try something, I post my code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When posting code on StackOverflow, always edit your question and post your code within there (I have already done this for you). I suggest looking at the http://stackoverflow.com/tour for details into how the site works

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working for a couple of reasons.

You are only changing the `href` of the link, not the `src` of the image; and you are not stopping the click event, meaning the anchor will just be followed, trying to load the image in the browser instead of as you want it:

```js
    function toggle(element) {
      var onLink = element.getAttribute('data-on');
      var offLink = element.getAttribute('data-off');
      var src = element.getAttribute("href"); //new image src
      if (element.getAttribute("href") == offLink){
        element.setAttribute("href", onLink);
      } else if (element.getAttribute("href") == onLink){
        element.setAttribute("href", offLink);
      }
      element.childNodes[1].setAttribute("src", src); //change the "src" attribute of the image.
      event.preventDefault(); //do not follow the link
    }
```

```html
<div class="col c1-8">
  <a id="btn4" onclick="toggle(this)" data-on="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/ff0000/0011ff&text=1" data-off="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/0011ff/ff0000&text=2" href="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/0011ff/ff0000&text=2">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/ff0000/0011ff&text=1">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. If you consider this to be the correct answer, please upvote and accept/tick it.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer.
I mean what you explain, but now my "data-on" and "data-off" are only a picture. What I want to do is, when I click, my picture change but I do an action too! "/trigger/7" or "/trigger/8" is an action in my case. Is it possible to do 2 things?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do multiple actions. What do '/trigger/7' and '/trigger/8' do? What have you tried? It may be outside the scope of this question - you may need to make a new question.

Comment: How do you do to do multiples actions? I send my html page on a specific device that I use for my work and /trigger/ does an anction on this device. It's specific. Do you understand?

Comment: If someone has a track to achieve 2 actions simultaneously, I thank him. I'm looking, I don't find.